# Pusher/Wrench on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP

Tags: php, pusher

A site I am currently grabbing a lot of data from via API recently implemented Pusher to provide real-time updates. They then link to the page http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries for client side libraries in several languages.

So the PHP client library linked to at http://pusher.com/docs/client_libraries appears to be bad.

First, the Git repo (via browser) doesn't download everything but once you get that figured out it still doesn't work. The basic flow is connect to Psher server with App key, then subscribe to one or more channels, then listen forever to those channels for updates.

The connect appears to work. The subscribe appears to work. The top level object from the PHP library leads to a recursion error (too deep) when I use var_export on it. Here's the resulting object after I subscribe to a channel:

```
Wrench\Payload\HybiPayload::__set_state(array( 'frames' => array ( 0 => Wrench\Frame\HybiFrame::__set_state(array( 'masked' => false, 'mask' => NULL, 'offset_payload' => 2, 'offset_mask' => 2, 'length' => 84, 'type' => NULL, 'buffer' => 'T{"event":"pusher:connection_established","data":"{\\"socket_id\\":\\"34937.7965561\\"}"}', 'payload' => '', )), ), ))
```

From there it waits for an update from the channel and when an update occurs I get the following:

```
Wrench\Payload\HybiPayload::__set_state(array( 'frames' => array ( 0 => Wrench\Frame\HybiFrame::__set_state(array( 'masked' => false, 'mask' => NULL, 'offset_payload' => 4, 'offset_mask' => 4, 'length' => 153, 'type' => NULL, 'buffer' => '~' . "\0" . '™{"event":"pusher:error","data":{"code":null,"message":"Pusher protocol versions <= 3 have been deprecated. Support will be removed after November 2013"}}', 'payload' => '', )), ), ))
```

and

```
array ( 0 => WrenchPusher\PusherMessage::__set_state(array( 'event' => 'pusher:connection_established', 'channel' => NULL, 'data' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'socket_id' => '34937.7965561', )), )), 1
=> WrenchPusher\PusherMessage::__set_state(array( 'event' => 'connection_established', 'channel' => NULL, 'data' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'socket_id' => '34937.7965561', )), )), 2
=> WrenchPusher\PusherMessage::__set_state(array( 'event' => 'pusher:error', 'channel' => NULL, 'data' => stdClass::__set_state(array( 'code' => NULL, 'message' => 'Pusher protocol versions <= 3 have been deprecated. Support will be removed after November 2013', )), )),
```

Now the obvious issue would be the part about version 3 not being supported. The script fails on a json_decode call which is expecting a string but is getting an object.

Despite several Google searches on the matter I have not been able to find an updated library.

Has anyone worked with a more up-to-date Pusher/Wrench PHP library? Any recommendations are welcome.

Thanks

---

Update 04/11/14:
Pusher support was kind enough to take 2 days to confirm that the library is in fact broken. And to tell me that they won't do anything about it. So if you want Pusher client in PHP you appear to be out of luck for now.

I also know Ruby and checked into that library. It also looked old but I didn't spend a lot of time looking into the details. After wasting my time on the broken PHP library I assumed the Ruby one was probably broken as well. Pusher seems to prefer javascript.

Comment: Hi Gabe, I'm sorry that you've been experiencing trouble getting things working.

As Loic has told you in your support ticket, the PHP client library is unofficial (not built by us) and therefore not supported.

The Ruby client library is updated often, in fact it was updated today. The Ruby library should work for your needs as discussed in the ticket.

I've taken your feedback on board and we'll use it when improving our libraries in the coming months.

Loic will be in touch via the existing ticket if you want to discuss this further.

Robin Hawkes,
Head of Developer Relations at Pusher

Comment: The app is already built in PHP. The Ruby client is a bandaid that makes the app much, much more complicated than if everything were in PHP. So I'm not real happy about it but I understand you can't support every git repo that says it will work with your service.

Comment: However, as I've discussed with Loic I felt it was unprofessional to link to a package that had been broken for 6 months and then take 3 days to tell me that you intended to do nothing about it. All in all Loic was polite but the answers took way too long and Loic's comment regarding how the Ruby client "should" work because it was recently updated suggests that despite taking 4 days to respond no one at Pusher bothered to test the Ruby client before sending me off to test it for you. Again, unprofessional.